# Python: testing for None, testing for boolean value

Tags: python

Is there any low-level, implementation-related difference (performance-ish) between these approaches..?

```
# check if string is empty
# the preferred way it seems [1]
if string:
    print string
else:
    print "It's empty."

# versus [2]
if string is '':

# or [3]
if string == '':
```

For example, when testing for `None`, I still find it more readable and explicit to do:

```
if some_var is not None:
```

..instead of..

```
if not some_var:
```

`if not some_var`, at least for me, always reads "if some_var does not exist".

Which is better to use, what are the proper use cases for `==`, `is` and bool-testing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never use `is` for (value) equality testing. Only use it to test for object identity. It may work for the example `if string is ''`, but this is implementation dependent, and you can't rely on it.

```
>>> a = "hi"
>>> a is "hi"
True
>>> a = "hi there!"
>>> a is "hi there!"
False
```

Other than that, use whatever conveys the meaning of your code best.

I prefer the shorter `if string:`, but `if string != '':` may be more explicit.

Then again `if variable:` works on every kind of object, so if `variable` isn't confined to one type, this is better than `if variable != "" and variable != 0:` etc.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer. And the "use whatever conveys the meaning of your code best" - this is a great thing to consider while coding, as well as when defending your solutions.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Tim Pietzcker's answer:

```
if string:
    print string
```

This tests if `string` evaluates to True. I.E.

```
>>> bool("")
False
>>> bool(None)
False
>>> bool("test")
True
```

So it's not only testing if it is empty, but if it is `None` or empty. This could have an impact depending on how you treat `None`/empty.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, don't use `if string is '':` because this is not guaranteed to work. The fact that CPython interns short strings is an implementation detail and should not be relied on.

Using `if string:` to check that `string` is non-empty is, I think, a Pythonic way to do it.

But there is nothing *wrong* about using `if string == ''`.

Comment: Alright, great. Could you expand on 'CPython interns short strings', or point me somewhere I could get more info?

Comment: ... I feel ridiculous. Must've been half-asleep, forgot to jfGit. Thanks!